# Process unique subsets of data

Tags: r, loops

This is my code to process data observations that are grouped to different associations. I would like to calculate for each observation the distance between his description and association in terms of euclidean distance.

The for loop subsets the datatable on group number. Each iteration the for loop selects a new group of rows to process. The problem is that I would like to store the calculations of each iteration. How could I do this?

Hopefully the situation is described unambiguously, questions are welcome. Any big deviations form current code or suggestions for research for new approaches are welcome as well!

Current situation:

```
       association description group
 1:        zzzz        zzzz     1        
 2:        zzzz        efgh     1        
 3:        zzzz        hijk     1        
 4:        aaaa        lmno     2        
 5:        aaaa        pqrs     2        
 6:        aaaa        tuvw     2        
 7:        aaaa        qyza     2        
 8:        aaaa        bcde     2        
 9:        bbbb       fqhij     3        
10:        cccc        klmn     4
```

Ideal solution:

```
       association description group distance
 1:        zzzz        zzzz     1        1
 2:        zzzz        efgh     1        0
 3:        zzzz        hijk     1        0
 4:        aaaa        lmno     2        0
 5:        aaaa        pqrs     2        0
 6:        aaaa        tuvw     2        0
 7:        aaaa        qyza     2        0
 8:        aaaa        bcde     2        0
 9:        bbbb       fqhij     3        0
10:        cccc        klmn     4        0
```

Library

```
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
```

Function to calculate distance

```
euclidean.dist <- function(x1, x2) {
  sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))
}
```

Description of data

```
association <- c('zzzz', 'zzzz', 'zzzz', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc')
description <- c('zzzz', 'efgh', 'hijk', 'lmno', 'pqrs', 'tuvw', 'qyza', 'bcde', 'fqhij', 'klmn')
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,4)
distance <- 0

mytable <- data.table(association,description,group,distance)
```

Index the for loop

```
ID <- length(unique(mytable$group))
```

To explore what happens, for now, set:

```
ID <- 1
```

For loop itself

```
for(i in ID) {

#for each unique group, select only the rows of one group at a time
#Get only the description column
  x1 <- filter(mytable, group == seq_along(unique(mytable$group))[[i]]) %>%
  select(description)

#For the same rows, select the specific association of the group of rows
  x2 <- filter(mytable, group == seq_along(unique(mytable$group))[[i]] & row_number() == 1 | row_number()== n()) %>%
select(association)

#Rename the association column to description, so as to enable rbind
  x2 <- rename(x2, description = association)
  x3 <- rbind(x2, x1)

#Create distance column to store the values
  x3$distance <- 0

#Transform to a corpus to weight the terms in each doc
  mycorpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x3))
  dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(mycorpus,
                        control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE),
                                       stopwords = FALSE))

#Create a matrix for measure
  x4 <- as.matrix(dtm)

#Get all rows, except the first row 
#The first row serves as input to calculate the euclidean for each row
  rows <- (seq(1, nrow(x3) -1) +1 )

#Calculate for all rows the distance
#Leave the first row empty, as it could be removed
  for(a in rows) {
    x3$distance[i] <- euclidean.dist(x4[1,], x4[a,])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following replaces `for` loops with `lapply`. I personally prefer using the `*apply` family of functions in R because it's clear what they will return, while `for` loops are not always as clear.

We are doing basically the same, iterating over each element of ID a sequence of functions. Not that the `for` loops inside this sequen has also been changed to a `lapply`.

```
lapply(1:ID, function(i) {

  x1 <- filter(mytable, group == seq_along(unique(mytable$group))[[i]]) %>%
    select(description)

  x2 <- filter(mytable, group == seq_along(unique(mytable$group))[[i]] & row_number() == 1 | row_number()== n()) %>%
    select(association)

  x2 <- rename(x2, description = association)
  x3 <- rbind(x2, x1)

  x3$distance <- 0

  mycorpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x3))
  dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(mycorpus,
                            control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE),
                                           stopwords = FALSE))

  x4 <- as.matrix(dtm)

  rows <- ( seq(1, nrow(x3) -1) + 1 )

  lapply(rows, function(a) {
    x3$distance[a] <<- euclidean.dist(x4[1, ], x4[a, ])
  })

  x3 %>% mutate(group = i)

}) %>% 
  do.call(what = bind_rows)
```